# Why is tomcat debug war different than manually created and copied war?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, war

Ive got a project which is a module consisting of three other jar projects and one web app.  When trying to debug inside of eclipse (tomcat 8), I get some classdefnotfound errors.  When I take the war and manually copy it and let the tomcat server run with it, it works fine.

I dig more digging and I found that the paths inside the deployed jars are different between the two deployment processes.  This seems to be the only significant differences:

**Tomcat/eclipse debugging (this one give class path errors):**

c:\servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\mywebapp\WEB-INF\lib\MyJar.jar\com\myjar

**Manually deployed (this one works):**

c:\servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\mywebapp\WEB-INF\lib\MyJar.jar\WEB-INF\classes\com\myjar

Again, it's the same WAR file. Why would debugging on the server change where files are placed inside the jar?  And any ideas on how to fix?

TIA

Comment: the "working" one does not look normal.  `WEB-INF` exists in WARs but not JARs

Comment: thats really strange then.  obviously something is hosed. thank you for that info